# How to detect invalid reads (using code not valgrind)

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Say you allocated a pointer to char like this

`char *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(char))`

If this ptr is passed to another function without passing its size, can we detect that ptr[10] is reading memory that does not belong to this pointer.

I know that if I used valgrind I will get and invalid read, but I want to write a code to throw an exception when this happens.

Comment: In this case you need to use corresponding types. Either standard, like `std::array<char, 10>`, `std::vector<char>` or something that you write youself or find in internet. Plain pointers don't have any additional information.

Comment: why wouldn't you want to pass size? even the operating system keeps track of how many bytes are allocated after the address returned by ```malloc()``` if it wasn't so, how would ```free()``` function  supposed to know what blocks to give back to an operating system?

Comment: Nope, the c++ standard doesn't track memory usage nor do most implementations without special debugging flags

Comment: Not very effectively. You can over-allocate and add [canary values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries) to the beginning and end, but by the time you check the canary, it may already be too late. it's better to use a data structure that builds in bounds checking.

Comment: Side note: When allocating dynamic storage in C++, reach for `malloc` and family dead last. The general order of preference is [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers), `new[]` and `delete[]`, `malloc` and friends and `free`.

Comment: @PIRIQITI is there a way that I could read this data will the program is running ?

Comment: Pedantic note: The only memory belonging to a pointer is the storage for the address, the pointer itself. The object the pointer points at, if any, is its own thing. A pointer knows where something could be, and that is all it knows.

Comment: @MIA I'm not sure but there could be some API which connects you to the linux kernel. Again I'm assuming that (don't take my word for it : ) just look up )

Comment: Minor point: `sizeof(char)` is 1. Always.

Comment: @user4581301 why is that? standard new calls malloc itself. The idiom `new[]` is a confusing aberration of the C++ language.

Comment: @NoleKsum Yes it does, but the point is you don't reach for `malloc` first. You grab it only after you've found the tools ahead of it unavailable or wanting, and that's usually when you're writing low-level plumbing. For example, when you are implementing `new` or an allocator to be used by a container. If you don't have a really good reason to use `malloc`, don't.

Comment: `malloc` just gives a blob of memory that the programmer must beat into the correct shape and manage womb-to-tomb. `new[]` will give a correctly-typed and initialized block of objects.  The smart pointer will give the same as `new[]` and ensure correct disposal. A container will give you the same as a smart pointer and provide a number of helper methods to automate common tasks, like trapping buffer overflows.

Comment: `new` calls the constructor of the object, `malloc` does not

Comment: @NoleKsum   The "standard new" is not required to call `malloc()` - and there are examples where it doesn't.  And a `new` expression does more than allocating memory (e.g. when creating an instance of `struct`/`class` types, it calls a constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to achieve this is using page guards. This is expensive though but will allow you to get an exception when it happens.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

void doit( char* p ) {
    for ( int j=0; j<20; ++j ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "%d %d\n", j, int(p[j]) );
    }
}

void trapped(int) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Memory violation");
}

int main() {
    signal( SIGSEGV, trapped );
    int pgsize = getpagesize();
    fprintf( stderr, "Page size: %d\n", pgsize );
    uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)mmap( NULL, 2*pgsize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
    MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 );
    if ( ptr == MAP_FAILED ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory map failed: %s\n", strerror(errno) );
        return 1;
    }
    int res = mprotect(ptr+pgsize,pgsize,PROT_NONE);
    if ( res!=0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to protect memory\n");
        return 2;
    }

    char* s = (char*)(ptr + pgsize - 10);

    try {
        doit( s );
    }
    catch( std::exception& ex ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Caught exception:%s\n", ex.what());
    }
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/oaMoTnaPo

The result of the run is:

```bash
Page size: 4096
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
Caught exception:Memory violation
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that this is very expensive in terms of *memory used* (especially for small allocations - since it always occupies ~8K for usual page sizes), but not in terms of CPU time. It also does not handle (admittedly rarer) underflow conditions, e.g. `ptr[-1]`.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that this approach is not standard C++ - it is specific to one OS (or OS family).

Comment: @Peter True. The C++ standard is very poor with respect to functionality.